# What does supervision mean in storm?

Tags: apache-storm

For example,in [storm document](http://storm.apache.org/releases/1.0.3/Setting-up-a-Storm-cluster.html),the last step is

> Launch daemons under supervision using "storm" script and a supervisor of your choice

What does word supervision mean in this place?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It just means you need some supervision (or we can say, monitoring)  on these daemon processes.

When the process is down, or has other errors, you can have a way to know in time.